# Calling a function in a thread

Tags: multithreading, rust

I am trying to implement multithreading in my program. In order to simplify my code and prevent excessively lengthy threads, I am exploring the possibility of invoking a function within my thread.

To further clarify, instead of this:

```
thread::spawn(|| -> do something)
```

I want to implement something like this:

```
fn my_function(){ do something }
thread::spawn(my_function())
```

---

To further show what I have experimented with, here is the normal and working implementation of my thread:

```
let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();

let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
    let var = 1;
    tx.send(var).unwrap();
});

let var = rx.recv().unwrap();
println!("Got: {}", var);

handle.join().unwrap();
```

However, now that I want to change this to the method I described, I get the error **error[E0434]: can't capture dynamic environment in a fn item**.
This is how I tried it:

```
let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();

let handle = thread::spawn(move || test());

fn test(){
    let var = 1;
    tx.send(var).unwrap();
}

let var = rx.recv().unwrap();
println!("Got: {}", var);
```

My questions now would be:

- Is there a way to call a function in a thread?
- If there is, how do I implement it?
- Are there any issues with concurrency that I would run into with this method?

Comment: Unlike closures, `fn`s cannot capture anything from their environment. You can define them in any scope, but they can't access variables in that scope.

Comment: May I ask the reason you want to do it this way? `thread::spawn(|| -> do something)` is the idiomatic way to run code that needs state.

Comment: @kmdreko: I could imagine `test` being awfully long. `thread::spawn(move || test(tx))` should serve well in that case, though.

Comment: You could also make `test` take the environment return a closure by defining it with `fn test(tx: mpsc::Sender<i32>) -> impl FnOnce() { move || { /* do something */ } }`, but I believe @Caesar's suggestion of `move || test(tx)` is usually better

Answer (score -2):

To refer to a function item instead of invoking it you must omit the parenthesis. I.e. `thread::spawn(my_function)`.

Comment: And, how do you hand over `tx` then? (Answer: either a closure (back to the start), or, on nightly rust, you implement `FnOnce` for some struct that holds `tx` (brr).)

Comment: Sure, but that's a different question.